# Ajax call works in FF, Chrome, and Safari but fails in IE with error Access denied

Tags: jquery, yql

In jQuery I wrote this simple ajax call to convert from one currency to another using Yahoo's YQL service.

```
function changeCurrency(amount, currency_from, currency_to) {
    var query = "select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair='" + currency_from + currency_to + "'";
    var urlservice = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + query + "&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlservice,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {

            $(xml).find('rate').each(function() {
                var rate = $(this).find('Rate').text();
                var result = Math.round(amount * rate * 100) / 100 ;
                $("#result").html(result + currency_to);
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            $.jGrowl(xhr + ' ' + status + " " + error);

        }
    });
}
```

Heres a [live version](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/3wxRr/2/) at jsfiddle.

Its working fine in Chrome, FF and Safari but fails in IE (9) with error message "Access denied". I guess it has to do with security but don't know how to solve it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087549/access-denied-to-jquery-script-on-ie) on Stack Overflow? Its quite similar problem and I think you might find the solution for your problem there :)

Comment: Thanks that's probably it - in the end however, I solved it by moving the yql call to a local web file handler (.ashx file) which then returned the conversion to the browser. This allowed me to solve the problem without having to write browser specific js code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set IE with low security settings

Comment: thanks, im using the default security settings when getting the error. It is not an option to go lower on security as it is for a worldwide webapp.