# How to Send POST data in IE CORS ( with XDomainRequest)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors

I've been looking for a simple example of how to send POST data in a cross domain request in IE (with the XDomainRequest object).

I've been able to make a simple POST request, but haven't been able to add POST data to it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var xdr;
function err() {
    alert('Error');
}
function timeo() {
    alert('Time off');
}
function loadd() {
    alert('Response: ' +xdr.responseText);
}
function stopdata() {
    xdr.abort();
}   
xdr = new XDomainRequest();
if (xdr) {
    xdr.onerror = err;
    xdr.ontimeout = timeo;
    xdr.onload = loadd;
    xdr.timeout = 10000;
    xdr.open('POST','http://example.com');
    xdr.send('foo=12345');
    //xdr.send('foo=<?php echo $foo; ?>'); to send php variable
} else {
    alert('XDR undefined');
}
```

Server side (php):

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

if(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA)) {
  parse_str($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA); // here you will get variable $foo
  if($foo == 12345) {
    echo "Cool!"; // This is response body
  }
}
```