# Simple jQuery post not working on Internet Explorer 9 (access denied)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, post

I programmed a validator with JQuery and PHP that works in all browsers except Internet Explorer 9. I get the error message "SCRIPT5: Access denied".

jQuery code

```
$('#contact-send').click(function(){
  $.post('functions/db-contact.php',{
    contact_name: $('#contact-name').val(),
    contact_email: $('#contact-email').val(),
    contact_subject: $('#contact-subject').val(),
    contact_message: $('#contact-message').val()
  },
  function(x){
    console.log(x);
  }
});
```

And this is the response (x):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
  <mail>
    <name>1</name>
    <email>1</email>
    <subject>1</subject>
    <message>1</message>
    <status>notok</status>
  </mail>
</response> 
SCRIPT5: Access denied
```

EDIT: I really have no idea what can be the error. I added the DB contact file. @Brad :)

```
<?php
include 'db_login.php';

$name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['contact_name']);
$email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['contact_email']);
$subject = mysql_escape_string($_POST['contact_subject']);
$message = mysql_escape_string($_POST['contact_message']);

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n";
echo "<response>\n";
echo "\t<mail>\n";

$i = 0;
if($name == 'type your name' or $name == '' or strlen(trim($name)) == 0){
  echo "\t\t<name>1</name>\n";
  $i = 1;
}

if($email == 'type your email address' or $email == '' or strlen(trim($email)) == 0){
  echo "\t\t<email>1</email>\n";
  $i = 1;
}

if($subject == 'type subject' or $subject == '' or strlen(trim($subject)) == 0){
  echo "\t\t<subject>1</subject>\n";
  $i = 1;
}

if($message == 'type your message on us' 
  or $message == '' or strlen(trim($message)) == 0){
    echo "\t\t<message>1</message>\n";
    $i = 1;
}

if($i == 1){
  echo "\t\t<status>notok</status>\n";
  echo "\t</mail>\n";
  echo "</response>";
  return false;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `d013f578`.`mail` (`id`, `name`, `email`, `subject`, `message`)
       VALUES (NULL, '".$name."', '".$email."', '".$subject."', '".$message."');";
$query = mysql_query($sql) or die;
echo "\t\t<status>ok</status>\n";
echo "\t</mail>\n";
echo "</response>";
?>
```

Unfortunately I have not found any usable tip on the internet.

Comment: I doubt this is all of the relevant code, yeah?  You can really reproduce the problem with only the code you posted?

Comment: I add the php file, maybe the error is there? :)

Comment: Just a guess: When the script returns false, PHP is putting an error status code in the HTTP response, and IE9 is translating that error into "Access denied". What happens if you change `return false;` to `exit;`?

Comment: does not work, the same error appears

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So, I have 100% the solution.
Instead jquery 1.8, I'm using jquery 1.6.4 and the problem was thus no longer available!

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution! First you have to change the JQuery code. You have to use xdr requests for Internet Explorer. Here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087549/access-denied-to-jquery-script-on-ie) you find more Informations about the JQuery code side. Thanks Stackoverflow awsome Community! :)

```
            $('#contact-send').click(function(){
                if($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
                    // Use Microsoft XDR
                    var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
                    xdr.open("POST", "functions/db-contact-xdr.php");
                    xdr.send("&contact_name="+$('#contact-name').val()+"&contact_email="+$('#contact-email').val()+"&contact_subject="+$('#contact-subject').val()+"&contact_message="+$('#contact-message').val()+""); 
                    xdr.onload = function () {
                        var dom = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                        dom.async = false;
                        dom.loadXML(xdr.responseText);
                        $("mail",xdr.responseText).each(function(id) {
                            var mail = $("mail",xdr.responseText).get(id);
                            }
                        });
                    };
                }else{
                    $.post('functions/db-contact.php',{
                        contact_name: $('#contact-name').val(), 
                        contact_email: $('#contact-email').val(),
                        contact_subject: $('#contact-subject').val(),
                        contact_message: $('#contact-message').val()
                    },function(x){
                        $("mail",x).each(function(id) {
                            var mail = $("mail",x).get(id);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
```

Even the PHP code I had to change to the data sent to the xdr request to use as POST variables, I used the PHP code taken from this page: http://saltybeagle.com/2009/09/cross-origin-resource- sharing demo.

Comment: it does not work :/ at the first click it works, but after the first click i got the same problem "SCRIPT5: ..." :/

Comment: So, I have 100% the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Comment out the `console.log` statement. In IE that causes the browser to choke unless the console (F12 developer tools) is open.