# GET request not firing in IE

Tags: backbone.js

This is killing me.

So I have a backbone site where when the user logs in, a GET request is made to the server and an access token is returned. Everything is working in FF, Chrome, IE10.

When I look at code inspector in IE9, the network tab does not list the get request to my API at all (not even as pending or failed). When I console log "error.status or error.statusText", it returns with:

```
0 Error: Access is denied.
```

My API has "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" enabled. I have also added "jQuery.support.cors = true;" to my initialize function in router.js. Now I am just out of ideas! I would really prefer not to setup a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using backbone than probably you are using jQuery too, so i think you should check this post : [Simple jQuery post not working on Internet Explorer 9 (access denied)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12336060/simple-jquery-post-not-working-on-internet-explorer-9-access-denied)