# JavaScript error "Access is denied" in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am getting this error when i run my webpage in IE(the code runs fine in other browsers).

This is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<--- some html code --->
<iframe src='http://localhost/page1.php' style="background: transparent; overflow: hidden; height: 210px; width: 390px;" frameborder="0"  />
</body>
</html>
```

This is page1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<form action="usercheck.php" method="POST">
USERNAME:<input name="uname" id="uname" type="text" maxlength="12" required/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is usercheck.php

```
<?php
//some php code    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<--- some html code --->
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when reach `usercheck.php` after clicking on submit button in `page1.php` i get the error `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js. Access is denied.` Here is an image of the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/diCoF.jpg . Then consequently i get the error that '$' symbol is not defined(which is due to the failure to load the jquery library).

EDIT-
I have tried including the jquery file in my server but still the error is comming. I have also tried this code for usercheck.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*! jQuery v1.10.1 | (c) 2005, 2013 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license
//@ sourceMappingURL=jquery.min.map
//and the rest of the jquery library...
</script>
</head>
<body>
<--- some html code --->
</body>
</html>
```

The error i am getting this time is this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/hR9aN.jpg (The original name of usercheck2.php is rscheck.php in my server). Then consequently i get the error that '$' symbol is not defined(which is due to the failure to load the jquery library). If i directly open the contents of page1.php (by the url- localhost/page1.php) then everything works fine.

This is the only code for which i am using JQuery:

```
if($("#pret").contents().text().search("NAMECHECK: NOTAVALIBLE")!=-1)
```

I could exclude jquery only if i can convert this code to javascript.

Comment: is internet accessible to you..??

Comment: Host it locally and call it. I've always linked to google, but that would probably be the easiest way around it.

Comment: Is `usercheck.php` loaded into the iframe?

Comment: Are you trying to modify the content of the outer html document (which includes the iframe) from the iframe?

Comment: i am not at all trying to modify the outer html page contents

Comment: I have edited my question some times so i request everyone to read the question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution to my question. The reason i wanted jquery was that i wanted to run this code:

```
if($("#pret").contents().text().search("NAMECHECK: NOTAVALIBLE")!=-1)
```

I removed jquery library and used this javascript to do the same:

```
var n=document.getElementById("pret").innerHTML.search("NAMECHECK: NOTAVALIBLE");
if(n != -1)
```

Now there is no error in the page and i am able to do what i wanted. So the error was caused as jquery library was not able to load in the webpage. But i dont know why even after downloading the jquery library in my server i was getting the same error ie. 'Access is denied'.

Answer (score 6):

This is a legit `jQuery 1.10.1` bug: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13980 .
  Using `jQuery 1.10.0`, or `1.10.2` the error no longer occurs.

Comment: Thanks this saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download `jquery.min.js` to your server and include it from there. For example:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.min.js"></script>`.

It looks like internet explorer can't access the resource: downloading it to your own server might solve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

The reason is in the `iframe`. As jQuery is loaded into the iframe from the external host, each time when you are trying to use any jQuery function in your main/outer html file, IE throws the error due to security reasons.

**1)** Either upload jQuery to your server,

**2)** or include it in main html file only (not in iframe).

Comment: The error is when the iframe page tries to access the jquery library

Comment: Then the best way is to upload jQuery (and maybe other js files you use) to your server, so all of them are hosted on your end.

Comment: Make sure that the locally hosted jQuery is included once, and try to include it in usercheck.php.

Comment: i have copy pasted the library in the webpage itself and then also i am getting the same error.

Comment: hm.. maybe the answers here will be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/5087606/841675

Comment: no use, as the webpage is not able to load the jquery library so it will identify '$' symbol and will not interpret the code

Comment: i need an alternative javascript for finding a string in a div, not for this