# copy the content inside a div to a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have this line in my JS

```
    document.getElementById("divtry").innerHTML = jsdat;
```

divtry is my div in HTML and I want the content which will be displayed inside that div (the content will be different from jsdat as the special characters like `&lt;br&gt;` and other special characters will be converted to HTML equivalent. Ex: `&lt;br&gt;` will be converted to `<br>` )

My problem is not yet solved.
my Input is this string.

```
     asd &lt;br&gt;sp
```

I need the output as below.

```
     asd
     sp
```

I am getting the output as below now.

```
     asd <br> sp
```

I tried the below code.

```
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = jsdat;
    var jsfin = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("o1").value = jsfin;
```

Output & o1 are my 2 div.
But I am getting correct output in output while in o1 I'm getting the input text intself.

So, my question is, how can I get the contents inside that div divtry and assign it to some variable. 
Can someone please give me a function which will do that.

Comment: Simple `var xyz=document.getElementById("divtry").innerHTML;`

Answer (score 3):

Did you try anything before asking this question?

```
jsdat = document.getElementById("divtry").innerHTML;
```

Comment: I tried that.
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = jsdat;
 jsfin = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
But I'm getting Access denied error.

Comment: @user3260554 Are you using Internet Explorer with jQuery 1.10.1? http://stackoverflow.com/a/18702901/2640017

Comment: I tried it. That one seems to be working. But my problem is not yet solved.
my Input is this string. 
        asd &lt;br&gt;sp
I need the output as below.
        asd
         sp
I am getting the output as below now.
         asd <br> sp
I tried the below code.
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = jsdat;
 var jsfin = document.getElementById("output").innerHTML;
 document.getElementById("o1").value = jsfin;
Output & o1 are my 2 div.
But I am getting correct output in output while in o1 I'm getting the input text intself.

Comment: @user3260554 can you try setting up a jsfiddle.net?