# getJSON access is denied in IE

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using jquery to process the json on another domain. I'm using json2.js and testing this in IE9 and IE10 
When I run this locally it works fine and sends the json successfully. However when I put this on another domain
I get an **"access is denied error"** in IE.

Here is the json that I'm sending.

```
$.getJSON("http://somedomain.com/send?callback=?", {"name":name,"user":user},null);
```

Another strange occurance is that when I put this on a server any object that I pass **json.stringify(obj);**
in the console returns **"Access is denied".** But if I pass **console.log(obj);** it returns the object 
successfully. But if I run the file locally I successfully return the json from **json.stringify(obj);**

I'm really really stumped on this any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this cross domain?

Comment: You're forgetting a `?` at the end of the URL.  It needs to be `http://somedomain.com/send?callback=?`.

Comment: @akatakritos yes this is cross domain

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087549/access-denied-to-jquery-script-on-ie) will help.

Comment: You need `$.ajax` with `jsonp` here search engines to your rescue.

Comment: Curious: why don't you have a success callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a cross-domain-request issue.

You are unable to use `getJSON()` to fetch data from another site due to browser policies.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5087549/access-denied-to-jquery-script-on-ie) for a workaround

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
$.getJSON('http://somedomain.com/send?callback=?','name='+name'&user='+user,function(response){
    alert('response is ' + reponse);
});
```